# Device and Disk Space Management

Tags: disk-space, ubuntu-16.04

I am having trouble freeing up space in my system. The output of the command `df` is:

[image: Terminal]

I'm not sure what the device `/dev/nvme0n1p5` is.

When I do `sudo umount /dev/nvme0n1p5` I get:

[image: Terminal]

I'm not sure where it is that I'm supposed to be freeing space, but this device is taking a considerable amount of space compared to all other devices.

Also, What exactly is this device? I tried researching it and found no answers.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/nvme0n1p5 is the device (disk partition) hosting your root (/)
It have to be mounted all the time.
You can use

```
du -h /
```

to get what is utilizing the /

Comment: Bad idea! this got me a huge list that took a lot of my terminal.